# What does "that's cooking/smoking" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

I'm watching a video about 100-meter sprint, [On YouTube - Why It's Almost Impossible to Run 100 Meters In 9 Seconds | WIRED@About 4:17](https://youtu.be/SdMo9hbt2nI?t=256) they said

> That's cooking.
>
> It's smoking.

What does it mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a (mainly US English) slang/casual figure of speech. If something is said to be 'hot', or some adjective implying great heat, it is exciting, special, impressive, very good, etc. Things that are cooking or smoking are necessarily hot.

> Smoking
>   informal Lively and exciting.
>
> ‘Wow! This band is really smokin'!’

[Smoking](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/smoking)